# Broken Screw Inside 2280 Riser on MOBO

Tags: ssd, motherboard, m.2

I bought a 500GB M.2 Samsung EVO and tried to install it on my Asus Z170S and ended up using a screw with the wrong threading and it snapped inside the riser.

Lesson learned the hard way. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get this thing out? There's no grip left on the screw whatsoever so I can't use pliers or anything to slowly twist it out.

[Broken Screw in 2280 Riser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFKZQ.jpg)

Comment: You could use some strong glue and put it on a pointy metal thing, then you should be able to screw it out

Comment: Googling "how to remove screw with broken head" results in several good options.  Personally, I've had luck with putting a rubber band across the hole, pushing the proper size screwdriver in to drive in the rubber, and turning it normally.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Make that an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've had luck with putting a rubber band across the hole, pushing the proper size screwdriver in to drive in the rubber, and turning it normally.

Answer (score 1):

Should probably just search for ["broken screw remover"](https://www.google.ca/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=broken%20screw%20remover), there's a bunch of specific products like these:

[image]
<sub>(source: [lowes.com](https://www.lowes.com/projects/images/how-tos/Hardware/remove-a-stripped-or-broken-screw-tools.jpg))</sub>

The tools are basically variations of backwards drill bits, or similar shaped tools. The main idea is to press down on the broken part (support the board from the other side or it could snap) and twist the part out. This link has some details: https://www.familyhandyman.com/tools/extract-a-broken-screw/view-all/

But since  you've got access to both sides of the hole (right?), use a regular drill bit (very slowly should work, unless it's really jammed) and it should eventually bite & remove it one way or the other.

PS. Christopher Hostage's comment idea sounds good too, especially if the broken part isn't stuck, try a bit of rubber over a screwdriver. (If that were an answer I'd upvote it. Edit: It is now, and in fact I just did)

---

Or you might be able to un-screw or un-bolt the whole connector, broken screw and all, if it's not permanently attached. Might need to do that anyway & replace with a non-messed-up one if you want to use a regular screw in the future. But once the broken screw's removed you'll probably have to use a nut & bolt.